# implementing hilt in android with kapt Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, kapt

I have been using hilt in my several android projects. But since I have updated my android studio to latest version Chipmunk// 2021.2.1, this error comes every time when I just build project

> Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
>
> > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

I am checking it on sample app which is just just one dependency injection, using hilt and kapt.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        // Hilt Classpath for Java
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1'


    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hiltkotlinpractice"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1")
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'

}
```

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App: Application()
```

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideInterface(): APIProvider {
        return APIProvider()
    }
}
```

```
class Repo @Inject constructor(
    val apiProvider: APIProvider
) {
    fun get() = apiProvider.getData()
}
```

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val TAG = "MainActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val repo  = Repo(APIProvider())
        Log.d(TAG, repo.get())

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using "annotationProcessor" instead of the "kapt" in the build.gradle dependencies. Worked for me.